# Order of centralizer in quotient is less than order than centralizer in group.

Tags: group-theory

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of the finite group $G$. How can i prove that $$\mid C_{G/N}(xN) \mid \; \leq \; \mid C_G(x) \mid$$ for every $x \in G$? I know that I have a simple proof for this if it is true that the order of the conjugacy class of $x$ is less than or equal the order of the conjugacy class of $xN$, i.e if $\mid CL(x) \mid \; \leq \; \mid CL(xN)\mid$. Any hints?

Comment: It is true that $|{\rm Cl}(x)| \le |N||{\rm Cl}(xN)$, which is enough to prove what you want.